# How to load an external website into my own website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I have tried using iframes, but it has not worked because of the same-origin error.

```
<div align="center">
<iframe src="http://sms.webzworld.com/" style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried a little bit of ajax but I was unsuccessful; I have very little knowledge of Ajax and jQuery, so I did not go too deep into this topic. That said, if there is a solution using Ajax and jQuery then I don't mind looking into it.

Now i am having a look at curl library in php to solve my problem. It doesnt load the external website but in a very hap hazard way.The code i use is as follows:

```
<?php
function Get_Domain_Contents($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;   
}

$url = 'http://sms.webzworld.com/';

$html = Get_Domain_Contents($url);

$html = "<base href='{$url}' />" . $html;

?>

<div src=""><?php echo $html; ?></div>
```

[This is how my site looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkpJQ.jpg)

In the plain white section is where i want the external website to load.
But after i use the curl code mentioned above i get this output.

[Output after the curl code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVjsQ.jpg)

As you can see that the external website overlaps my own website.

So can anybody help me out with an effective solution?

Comment: So load the content in an iframe. FYI: The 3rd party can easily add a script to their page that hijacks your site when you scrape and rehost.

Comment: Its probably because their css is overwriting yours. You aren't sanitizing their body. As much as I hate iframes, that is really your only answer. Unless you can sanitize the CSS from their site, but then you will have issues with they way their stuff looks. (not to mention, still giving a website you dont control, free reign on your site). Best solution would be to attempt to recreate what they are doing, in your own code. Much safer to your site, and you have complete control over the layout

Comment: You mentioned you tried iframe (I saw that, and forgot about it... Sorry). Looking at the headers, `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN`. So they do not want their stuff framed. What is the purpose of your site? Why are you attempting to load their site, anyways? There is probably other ways to achieve what you are looking for